# How to send non value transaction, just simple indexation payload an integer or float data to same messageid everytime using iota_client in Python?

Tags: transaction, address, python

I am sending integer and float data to IOTA ledger at Chrysalis Devnet using iota_client Python library. Each time I send new subset of data or want to update the same data, client = iota_client.Client() sends it to default test network at different messageid. How I can send data to same messageid as before so at receiving end I don't have to change messageid.

I have tried to create my own addresses or tried to use data index to send data to same messageid eveytime but with no success as I could not find the right client library functions.Any help or guidance is much appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

`message_id` is a unique id that refers to the given message in the network.

You can probably look for one of these [MQTT topics](https://wiki.iota.org/iota.rs/examples/mqtt/) to listen to instead. Maybe, `messages/indexation/{index}` is closest to what you're looking for. You can try them out [here](https://studio.asyncapi.com/?load=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iotaledger/tips/main/tips/TIP-0016/event-api.yml) from TIP-16.

However, these topics will change if you use Shimmer Network, where you can use something like `blocks/tagged-data/{tag}` instead

Comment: May be MQTT topic messages/indexation/{index} can be used for retreiving the data but how we can write data to same messageid. For example if same data column needs to be added or updated with new values than it will be stored with its new messageid right?

Comment: Exactly. Hence suggested to use `index` instead. Same `message_id` can NOT be used.